# Any plugins to help with multilingual content?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, multi-language

I'm taking classes in Spanish and would like to keep a blog to track my progress, where I can translate random pieces of text, post pictures and describe them in Spanish etc.

Are there any plugins that would help with this? Maybe something that automatically detects the language and colors it a different color?

Comment: from what you're saying, you don't need a plugin that handles multilingual content, you just need to color your text that you translate in Spanish from the post editor :)

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of good multilingual plugin but what your asking for is very specific and unique.

I would find one that translates the language into a easily customizable format ( Like a post) where you can use a div for outputting a diff color.

For instance wrap the translation in div .spanish {color:red}